# How to get intersection of two text columns in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, text, nlp

I have a df that looks like this:

```
id  textcol1             textcol2             ... coln
1   blue bowl            green bowl           ... xxx
2   purple sheet         green grass          ... xxx
3   ground black pepper  ground black pepper  ... xxx
```

and so on...

I want to get the percentage of common words between textcol1 and textcol2

```
id  textcol1             textcol2             ... coln intersection
1   blue bowl            green bowl           ... xxx  50
2   purple sheet         green grass          ... xxx  0
3   ground black pepper  ground black pepper  ... xxx  100
```

After an embarrassingly long time I've come up with the following solution

```
df['intersection'] = [(len(set(a) & set(b)) / float(len(set(a) | set(b))) * 100) for a, b in zip(df.textcol1, df.textcol2)]
```

But the results are not what I would expect, for example passing "ground black pepper" twice yields 93.33333333333330.

I've gone through all the usual cleaning steps - removing whitespace, etc. - but can't figure out what the issue is here.

What am I missing?

Comment: @salted according to my example which is ignoring duplicate occurrences, the percentage would be 100%, since the count of common words is 3 and the count of all words are 3, too. After your comment I understand now, that you mean the common words of textcol2 in textcol1 (and not both), which is a little bit different of all common words in both columns. Then for example, the percentage for the first row would be 50% instead of 33.3%.

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing a generic text comparison function first, something like `text_diff` below that computes a simple token overlap between two texts (aka `set`s of tokens):

```py
def text_diff(text1, text2):
    return 100 * len(text1.intersection(text2)) / min(map(len, (text1, text2)))
```

Then you can get the two columns you want to compare and turn them into sets of tokens, e.g.,

```py
df2 = df.filter(like="textcol").applymap(str.split).applymap(set)
```

Result:

```py
                   textcol1                 textcol2
id                                                  
1              {bowl, blue}            {bowl, green}
2           {sheet, purple}           {grass, green}
3   {pepper, black, ground}  {pepper, black, ground}
```

So you can easily apply the function by doing

```py
>>> df2.apply(lambda row: text_diff(*row), axis=1)
id
1     50.0
2      0.0
3    100.0
dtype: float64
```

That way you can easily tweak and/or replace your `text_diff` function. Do some research on text similarity measures, too, and use existing tools if applicable. [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) could be worth a shot, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty way. but might need to be adjusted based on the text, and how you define an intersection to not a robots points.

```py
def intersections(x):
    combined = x['textcol1'].split(' ') + x['textcol2'].split(' ') 
    total = {i:combined.count(i) for i in combined}
    return sum([v for v in total.values() if v != 1]) / len(combined) * 100

df['intersections'] = df.apply(intersections, axis=1)
print(df)

              textcol1             textcol2  intersections
0            blue bowl           green bowl           50.0
1         purple sheet          green grass            0.0
2  ground black pepper  ground black pepper          100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers are good, but you want to get the percentage of common words between an row of `textcol1` and `textcol2`.

To obtain this we have to retrieve all tokens from row and count all occurrences between the word tokens in the row of `textcol1` and `textcol2`.

The percentage of common words in the first row must be 0.33, because we compare against a the set words = {bowl, blue, green}.
`textcol1` and `textcol2` got only one word in common, common_words : {bowl}

As a result we get: `#common_words / #all_words = 1 / 3 = 0.33`

An example:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add


def fun(text1, text2):
    text1_tokens = text1.split(' ')
    text2_tokens = text2.split(' ')
    text1_set = set(text1_tokens)
    text2_set = set(text2_tokens)

    text_intersect = list(set.intersection(text1_set, text2_set))
    all_tokens = list(set.union(text1_set, text2_set))
    common_token_count =  list(map(lambda x: all_tokens.count(x), text_intersect))

    if len(common_token_count) > 0:
        common_token_count = reduce(add, common_token_count)
        return f"{common_token_count/len(all_tokens):.2f}"
    else:
        return 0.00
    

df["intersection"] = df.apply(lambda x: fun(x["text1"], x["text2"]), axis=1)
```

The output:

```
0   blue bowl   green bowl  0.33
1   purple sheet    green grass 0.00
2   ground black pepper ground black pepper 1.00
```

Comment: In your example, are you counting the space between "blue"/"green" and "bowl"?

Comment: No, I don't count the spaces. The output might be a little bit unformatted. The words are splitted by space and the sample strings don't contain multiple spaces or special characters. The sample strings are like "blue bowl", which results in a list ["blue", "bowl"] without space.

Comment: You have the first results as 33 % instead of 50 % why is that? you should have 50%

Comment: @onyambu
The set of all words in the first column is = {blue, green, bowl}, because multiple occurrences of the same word like 'bowl' aren't taken into counting.

common words are: "bowl"
all words are: "blue", "green", "bowl"
we divide: common words / all words

and we get: 1/3 = 0.33

.So 0.5 is wrong, because you take the common word occurrences twice into account, for e.g:

common words are: "bowl", "bowl"
all words are: "bowl","bowl", "blue", "green"

and we get: 2/4 = 0.5

Hope it helped

Comment: But that is not what OP wants. Also can you give an example that will produce 50%?

Comment: He wants the common word percentage between the two columns, so I think it is. Since the cardinality of the set of common words is  1 and the cardinality of the set all words between the columns is 3. An example for 50% would be the following strings in the columns: "bowl" and "fish bowl", common words are "bowl" all words are: "bowl", "fish" and we divide as before common words / all words and we get 1/2 = 0.5

Comment: When I try your function it just outputs all 0's

Comment: I cannot tell you why, but here is the colab, which I am using. Hope it helps.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aGlc-AF3S22Fz-a9upgbno9qFPyOQ1_R?usp=sharing

Comment: I think the issue was trying to add an extra step in the tokenization - I reworked it a bit and it seems to run now